# Using docker volumes in packer build

Tags: docker, docker-volume, packer

Is it possible to use existing docker or external volumes in/during packer build?

I saw in https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker/:

> `"VOLUME /test1 /test2"`

What does it exactly mean? *"VOLUME String EX: "VOLUME FROM TO""* doesn't explain much. Is `/test1` from host?

I also saw in https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/docker/#volumes:

> `volumes` (map[string]string) - A mapping of additional volumes to mount into this container. The key of the object is the host path, the value is the container path.

How can I make use of that? Where/how can I put/declare it , suppose that I want to map `/etc/dnsmasq.d/` host path into the container, during build time and run time as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has the same meaning as the [corresponding Dockerfile directive](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) (indeed, all of the directives in that section of the Packer documentation are Dockerfile commands).  You probably don't need or want it.

This is different from the [`docker run -v` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only) to mount content into a container.  You cannot specify mount options like this at container build time (whether using `docker build` or Packer).  You don't need to specify a `VOLUME` to be able to mount content on some container directory.

The Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive isn't needed for most common uses and mostly only has confusing side effects.  You do not need it to mount configuration into your application; you do not need it to overwrite application source code with a development tree; the most obvious thing it does do is prevent future `RUN` instructions from having an effect.  I'd avoid it unless you understand in detail what it does and why you want it.

Comment: Oh, OK, that's not the kind of answer I'd expect, but can be the one I accept, :). Thanks, but will do in two days, to see if there is any other replies I may get, :)